# Can't Comment On Duplicate Question

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

This is a bug. It ain't April Fools Day or is a new update to the SE sites. For some reason, I can't comment on a duplicate question on a closed question on the Samsung Galaxy 2, browser is Google. The situation is that I can't find the "Add Comment" button:
[image]

I understand that you can't ***answer*** but you should be able to/can comment on that post. You can still edit, share, etc. as usual but can't comment. So why can't I comment on a duplicate post, whether it is an answer or question?

Note:

> Never, Never Ever argue with Oded. Learned that the hard way...

And I can comment on closed posts. Just not duplicates